images paths in the build when they are provided from a JSON
I have a Svelte 5 app (not SvelteKit) where the data, including images paths, is provided from JSON.
Images are in src/lib directory, as advised in the official Svelte doc.
data.json:
[
    {
        "title": "tile 1",
        "images": [
            { "src": "/src/lib/images/tile1a.jpg" },
            { "src": "/src/lib/images/tile1b.jpg" }
        ]
    },
    {
        "title": "tile 2",
        "images": [
            { "src": "/src/lib/images/tile2a.jpg" },
            { "src": "/src/lib/images/tile2b.jpg" }
        ]
    }
]

The parent component loads the data and pass it to the child components:
<script lang="ts">
import data from "$lib/data.json"
import ChildComponent from "$lib/components/ChildComponent.svelte"
</script>

<main>
    {#each data as tile}
        <ChildComponent title={tile.title} images={tile.images} />
    {/each}
</main>

And the child components use the images files paths as img src attribute:
<script lang="ts">

interface Props {
    title: string
    images: { src: string }[]
}
const { title, images }: Props = $props()

</script>

<div class="tile">
    <span>{title}</span>
    {#each images as i}
        <img src='{i.src}' />
    {/each}
</div>

This works as intended when running with Vite in dev mode (vite dev), as the images paths exist.
But when running a built version of the app (vite build, then vite preview), images are not found, since their paths is not converted to the dist folder.
I guess the images should be imported as Svelte imports (import Image from '/src/lib/images/tile1a.jpg') so that they can be resolved in the distributable build (dist) directory, but how can one do that with dynamic paths?

Note that the documentation you linked to is for SvelteKit.

Indeed, thanks. Although I couldn't find any doc about images loading good practices for Svelte in the official doc.

You can import the images via glob import and use that mapping to look up the asset URL. Something along the lines of:
<script lang="ts">
  import data from "$lib/data.json";
  const imageMap: Record<string, string> = import.meta.glob(
    "$lib/images/*",
    { eager: true, import: "default" },
  );
</script>

<main>
  {#each data as tile}
    {@const images = tile.images.map(i => ({ ...i, src: imageMap[i.src] }))}
    <ChildComponent title={tile.title} {images} />
  {/each}
</main>


Great answer. I wish one could find some documentation about that in the Svelte (not SvelteKit) official docs.

Svelte cannot have anything like that in its documentation because this is a bundling and build tool issue. Svelte itself is completely agnostic about anything outside of bare component compilation.

Put your assets in a public dir at the root, they'll be served during dev too. Once you get your routes matching your JSON in dev, you run npm run build and it will place the files from public into dist. To be served there on npm run preview and wherever you host it.
According to Vite's documentation:

The public Directory
If you have assets that are:

Never referenced in source code (e.g. robots.txt)
Must retain the exact same file name (without hashing)
...or you simply don't want to have to import an asset first just to get its URL [I believe this to be your case]

Then you can place the asset in a special public directory under your project root. Assets in this directory will be served at root path / during dev, and copied to the root of the dist directory as-is.
The directory defaults to <root>/public, but can be configured via the publicDir option.
Note that:

You should always reference public assets using root absolute path - for example, public/icon.png should be referenced in source code as /icon.png.
Assets in public cannot be imported from JavaScript.


If you werent to change your code you'd only have to have your folder structure look something like this:
 node_modules
 dist
 ├  ...all your stuff from build
 src
 ├  lib
 │  └  ...your other library stuff
 ├  components
 │  ├  ChildComponent.svelte
 │  └  ...your other components
 public (put the stuff to be served here)
 ├  lib
 │  └  images
 │     ├  tile1a.jpg
 │     ├  tile2a.jpg
 │     ├  tile1b.jpg
 │     └  tile2b.jpg
 ├ package.json
 ├ vite.config.js
 └ ...other stuff at the root

Just npm run build and it should work when running preview

I would not recommend putting stuff in public out of laziness. The files will not be served with caching headers because the file name is always the same (otherwise you could not properly update the files later). Via import, the assets get a hash and can be cached indefinitely, on change a new URL is created causing a cache miss.
